# Forward declared singleton class with a friend function from the class with the forward declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, return, singleton, friend-function

I hope this is a coherent question... I have a singleton class definition like:

```
#include A.h

class Singleton
{
public:
   // If I change this to a return by pointer, it works fine. But reference gives me problems.
   static Singleton &getInstance();
   Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;
   void operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;
   ~Singleton();

   friend void A::friendMethodinA();
private:
   Singleton();
   void methodOnlyNeededByA();
}
```

The class definition is:

```
Singleton &Singleton::getInstance()
{
   static Singleton instance;
   return instance;
}

Singleton::~Singleton() {}

Singleton::Singleton() {}

void Singleton::methodOnlyNeededByA() { // method body. }
```

My class A declaration is:

```
#pragma once

class Singleton;

class A
{
public:
   void friendMethodinA();
private:
   // This is what I'm not sure about. I tried
   // Singleton &mSingleton = Singleton::getInstance(); This gives me "use of undefined type 'Singleton'" error. I can't #include Singleton.h because of the friend function.
   // Singleton mSingleton = Singleton::getInstance(); This gives me "cannot be reference -- it is a deleted function" error.
   Singleton mSingleton; // This gives me "A::mSingleton uses undefined class 'Singleton'" error.
}
```

I would really like to return the singleton by reference rather than pointer bto avoid null checks and dereferencing the pointer every time I use it. Is there a way to achieve this without completely refactoring to avoid using friend functions?

The purpose of this friend function is the method `methodOnlyNeededByA()`. Since it only ever needs to be called by Class A, I do not want to put it in the public interface of the Singleton.

Comment: **"I would really like to return the singleton by reference rather than pointer"** - The code you presented already returns the singleton by reference rather than pointer.

Comment: @Galik yes, but this code doesn't compile. I get compiler errors as I mentioned in inline comments. None of the assignment operations I tried in Class A are valid.

Comment: Did you try the code from the top answer of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern

Comment: @Galik yeah, my singleton implementation is exactly that. It's the friend function that accesses private member function of the singleton that is giving me problems.

Comment: The forward declaration of `class Singleton;` doesn't contain enough information about `Singleton` to instantiate one. All `A` can know at this point is that `Singleton` exists. It doesn't know about any of the methods of `Singleton`, so you can't call them here. You can't include Singleton.h because of circular reference and R Sahu picks it up from there, so I'm not submitting my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resolve the compiler error by:

1. Using a reference type as the member variable.

   ```
   Singleton& mSingleton;
   ```

   and then
2. Intializing it in the constructor.

However, the more important point I want to make is: Don't use a member variable of type `Singleton`. When you need to use the class, simply call `Singleton::getInstance()`. You can store a reference to the returned object in a function local variable or just use the returned reference.

```
auto& ref = Singleton::getInsance();
ref.methodOnlyNeededByA();
```

or

```
Singleton::getInsance().methodOnlyNeededByA();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! "Don't use a member variable of type" was what I needed :)

Comment: @swdon, I'm glad I was able to help.